# Чтение из файла, функция get()

Tags: c++

Планировалось, что этот участок кода будет открывать файл, пронумеровывать и выводить по строкам его содержимое, но на деле в консоль выводится сразу все содержимое файла. По описанию на сайте http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/ в данном случае get()
должен читать до символа перевода строки. В чем же проблема?

```
std::ifstream is;
is.open(file.txt);
std::streambuf *buf = is.rdbuf();
do
{
    is.get(*buf,'\n');
    cout<<i<<". "<<buf<<"\n";
}while(is.eof());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char buf[100000];

int main(){
ifstream is;
is.open("log.txt");
for (int i=0; ;i++){
    is.getline(buf,100000);
    if (is.fail())
        break;
    cout << i <<". "<<buf<<endl;
}
```

Пример работающего кода.

В вашем примере вы используете `is.get(*buf,'\n');` т.е.  `istream& get (streambuf& sb, char delim);` следовательно вы должны выводить то что получили в результате работы функции. Дальше `is.eof()`  будет всегда `true` т.к. мы ранее прочитали `is.rdbuf();` (до конца файла). переменную `i` я у вас вообще не нашёл. Имя файла кстати тоже в кавычки брать надо.

Если вы не хотите выделять статически память под буфер то можно писать так:

```
int main(){
 ifstream is;
 is.open("log.txt");
 string buf;
 for (int i=0; ;i++){
   getline(is,buf);
   if (is.fail())
     break;
   cout << i <<". "<<buf<<endl;
 }
```

}